# How to set keyboard repeat delay in Weston

Tags: linux, configuration, keyboard, wayland, yocto

I'm working on a platform with Wayland & Weston and I so far only have the Wayland-Terminal application installed. I can start it but it's unusable because I cannot type a single letter, it constantly gets repeated many times. It appears as if the keyboard repeat delay is set way too low. According to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/weston.ini.5.html#keyboard%20section I have added a `[keyboard]` section to `/etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini` and it now looks like:

```
[core]
idle-time=0
require-input=false
repaint-window=17
[keyboard]
repeat-rate=50
repeat-delay=500
```

but after a reboot, the keyboard remains unusable, there does not seem to be any change at all. Anyone that can assist in this matter?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come to a usable keyboard configuration with the following values (which I know are far from optimal but are good enough for me for now):

```
[core]
idle-time=0
require-input=false
repaint-window=17
[keyboard]
repeat-rate=0
repeat-delay=500
```